Error Ansible setup
Im setting up Ansible AWX on my ubuntu 22.04 machine. When running the install playbook ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml I get the error below. Any ideas how to solve this error?enter code here
TASK [local_docker : Remove AWX containers before migrating postgres so that the old postgres container does not get used] ***
task path: /opt/awx-17.0.1/installer/roles/local_docker/tasks/compose.yml:39
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.docker_compose to community.docker.docker_compose
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286 `" ) && sleep 0'
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.docker_compose to community.docker.docker_compose
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-55012_sn_58np/tmp1ourujow TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286/AnsiballZ_docker_compose.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286/AnsiballZ_docker_compose.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286/AnsiballZ_docker_compose.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545879.5251415-55622-50488307772286/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_docker_compose_payload_pxd37bxc/ansible_docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/module_utils/common.py", line 248, in __init__
    super(AnsibleDockerClientBase, self).__init__(**self._connect_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_version": "auto",
            "build": false,
            "ca_path": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "debug": false,
            "definition": null,
            "dependencies": true,
            "docker_host": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
            "env_file": null,
            "files": null,
            "hostname_check": false,
            "nocache": false,
            "profiles": null,
            "project_name": null,
            "project_src": "/root/.awx/awxcompose",
            "pull": false,
            "recreate": "smart",
            "remove_images": null,
            "remove_orphans": false,
            "remove_volumes": false,
            "restarted": false,
            "scale": null,
            "services": null,
            "ssl_version": null,
            "state": "absent",
            "stopped": false,
            "timeout": null,
            "tls": false,
            "tls_hostname": null,
            "use_ssh_client": false,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Error connecting: Error while fetching server API version: Not supported URL scheme http+docker"
}
...ignoring

TASK [local_docker : Run migrations in task container] **************************************************
task path: /opt/awx-17.0.1/installer/roles/local_docker/tasks/compose.yml:45
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-55012_sn_58np/tmp0arrzo9c TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756/AnsiballZ_command.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718545880.0966744-55646-60279963746756/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "docker-compose run --rm --service-ports task awx-manage migrate --no-input",
    "delta": "0:00:00.367649",
    "end": "2024-06-16 13:51:20.604797",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "docker-compose run --rm --service-ports task awx-manage migrate --no-input",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/root/.awx/awxcompose",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "expand_argument_vars": true,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2024-06-16 13:51:20.237148",
    "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py\", line 633, in send\n    conn = self.get_connection_with_tls_context(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py\", line 489, in get_connection_with_tls_context\n    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_host(\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py\", line 245, in connection_from_host\n    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py\", line 257, in connection_from_context\n    raise URLSchemeUnknown(scheme)\nurllib3.exceptions.URLSchemeUnknown: Not supported URL scheme http+docker\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version\n    return self.version(api_version=False)[\"ApiVersion\"]\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py\", line 181, in version\n    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py\", line 46, in inner\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 237, in _get\n    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py\", line 602, in get\n    return self.request(\"GET\", url, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py\", line 589, in request\n    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py\", line 703, in send\n    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py\", line 637, in send\n    raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)\nrequests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Not supported URL scheme http+docker\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/bin/docker-compose\", line 8, in <module>\n    sys.exit(main())\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py\", line 81, in main\n    command_func()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py\", line 200, in perform_command\n    project = project_from_options('.', options)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py\", line 60, in project_from_options\n    return get_project(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py\", line 152, in get_project\n    client = get_client(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py\", line 41, in get_client\n    client = docker_client(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py\", line 170, in docker_client\n    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 197, in __init__\n    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version\n    raise DockerException(\ndocker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: Not supported URL scheme http+docker",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py\", line 633, in send",
        "    conn = self.get_connection_with_tls_context(",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py\", line 489, in get_connection_with_tls_context",
        "    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_host(",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py\", line 245, in connection_from_host",
        "    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)",
        "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py\", line 257, in connection_from_context",
        "    raise URLSchemeUnknown(scheme)",
        "urllib3.exceptions.URLSchemeUnknown: Not supported URL scheme http+docker",
        "",
        "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:",
        "",
        "Traceback (most recent call last):",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version",
        "    return self.version(api_version=False)[\"ApiVersion\"]",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py\", line 181, in version",
        "    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py\", line 46, in inner",
        "    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 237, in _get",
        "    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py\", line 602, in get",
        "    return self.request(\"GET\", url, **kwargs)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py\", line 589, in request",
        "    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py\", line 703, in send",
        "    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py\", line 637, in send",
        "    raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)",
        "requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Not supported URL scheme http+docker",
        "",
        "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:",
        "",
        "Traceback (most recent call last):",
        "  File \"/usr/local/bin/docker-compose\", line 8, in <module>",
        "    sys.exit(main())",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py\", line 81, in main",
        "    command_func()",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py\", line 200, in perform_command",
        "    project = project_from_options('.', options)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py\", line 60, in project_from_options",
        "    return get_project(",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py\", line 152, in get_project",
        "    client = get_client(",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py\", line 41, in get_client",
        "    client = docker_client(",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py\", line 170, in docker_client",
        "    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 197, in __init__",
        "    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()",
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version",
        "    raise DockerException(",
        "docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: Not supported URL scheme http+docker"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}

